# Change Button Foreground in :pointerover and :pressed states

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

In fluent theme i can't change button Foregrounds in this states. In Github i [find](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/src/Avalonia.Themes.Fluent/Controls/Button.xaml) this code:

```
<Style Selector="^:pointerover /template/ ContentPresenter#PART_ContentPresenter">
      ...
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
 </Style>
```

But my project can't build with Foreground on `ContentPresenter#PART_ContentPresenter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ContentPresenter` does not have a `Foreground` property. If you target a `TextBlock` you could use attached property `TextBlock.Foreground`. If not, there are [child and descendant selectors](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/styling/selectors#child) you may want to take look at.

Also the nested selector `^` does not seem to be documented (it's pretty new it seems), maybe it would be safer to just use name of the control (`Button` in your case) for now.